# Getting documents from Mongolab with Javascript XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, mlab

I'm trying to get a specific document without knowing the ID of this document. Since I'm using Mongolab, I can't query the IDs because I let Mongolab generate these.

I've managed to alert the entire collection, but as soon as I try to add query attributes it pops up "undefined" in the alert!

Code that works, and alerts the entire collection:

```
var xhrGet = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhrGet.open("GET", 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/MYBASE/collections/MYCOLLECTION&apiKey=MYAPIKEY');

    xhrGet.onreadystatechange = function(){
      existingUrl = xhrGet.responseText;
      alert(existingUrl);
    }
    xhrGet.send();
```

Providing snip of the Mongolab JSON format:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "MongoLab ID"
  },
  "visited": {
    "url": "SomeURL",
    "weight": 1
  }
}
```

My problem is that I only want to access the "url" field of this JSON file. When I try to add for instance .visited or .visited.url to the alert; it becomes "undefined".

```
alert(existingUrl.visited);
```

and

```
alert(existingUrl.visited.url);
```

are both undefined!

Any thoughts and sollutions to this?

**Solution** (with help from @furrypet and some more detailed reading):

```
var xhrGet = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhrGet.open("GET", 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/MYBASE/collections/MYCOLLECTION?q={"visited.url": "' + THEURL + '"}&apiKey=MYAPIKEY');
    xhrGet.onreadystatechange = function(){
      var response = JSON.parse(xhrGet.responseText);
      for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
        var temp = response[i];
        alert(temp.visited.url);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using responseText, the format format of your response is plain text, meaning you cannot manipulate it like a JSON object.

You could change the method used, for instance replacing it with responseXML to get it a in a XML format, but what I could suggest you is to use JSON.parse to turn your response string into a JSON.

So add something like :

```
response = JSON.parse(existingUrl);
```

And you should be able to query response object. For more information check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest and here https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/JSON/parse

EDIT :

Following OP's suggestion, here's a simple example :

```
// The string should be a valid JSON
 var jsonString = '{"hello":"world"}';
 var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString); // Returns 'Object { hello: "World" }

 // Now you can use jsonObj like a regular JSON Object. Therefore : 
 jsonObj.hello; // will output "World"

 // Reciprocally, if you want to turn a JSON into a string, you may use:
 JSON.stringify(jsonObj); // returns "{"hello":"world"}"
```

Comment: This worked, thanks for your help! If anyone else wonders: What @furrypet suggested makes JSON-objects of the response from server. So if you would like to use these, just make a loop to iterate them and print the result as you wish!

Comment: @chrisv yes exactly,  thanks for precision I might edit my answer with your comment :)